# Excel - Get value of a column in a row where match found in another column

Tags: excel

[image]

I need to track where value in `J` column starts appearing zero. In following table, its 7th row. From this row, I need to get value of `D` column to appear in some designated Cell outside this table. In this case it would be `11 y, 2 m`.

I used `offset` function, that gives me first occurrence of zero in `J` column. But I'm not sure how to lookup different column (`D`) from the same row to fetch it's value.

My formula: `=OFFSET(J1,MATCH(0,J:J,0)-1,0)`

Here actual data starts at first row; hence 1 is used above. It correctly returns first zero (0) occurrence in J column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the column is sorted so that the first zero is the only zero that matters, one of many solutions is Index Match.

`=Index(D:D,Match(0,J:J,0))`

`Index` returns the value of nth position in a list.  `Match` returns the position of the of the first match in a list; the `0` at the end is a parameter to specify an exact match.  When both lists are the same length, such as two columns in a table, then you use `Match` to find the index and use `Index` to find the value of an arbitrary column.

So, in this example, `Match` returns 7.  The 7th position in Column D is 11y, 2m

In the very near future (or right now for some people) you will be able to use `XLookup` to do the same thing.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I was not aware of `Index` function.

Comment: @benjamin54 Happy to help!